# dequeue object from front of queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter-canvas

Am trying to dequeue a random shape from the front of the queue in my tkinter program. I have tried the `is_empty()` method but I seem to get an error.

```
>>> AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'pop'.
```

Any help would be great thanks !
This is the queue class I'm using

```
class Queue:
  def __init__(self):
    self.items = []
  def is_empty(self):
    return self.items == []
  def size(self):
    return len(self.items)
  def enqueue(self, item):
    self.items.insert(0, item)
  def dequeue(self):
    return self.items.pop(0)
  def peek(self):
    return self.items[0]
```

class Recta:

```
def __init__(self, height=60, width=80 ):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.create_buttons()
    self.canvas = Canvas(root)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.queue = Queue()  



def remove_triangle(self):
    if not self.queue.is_empty(): 
         self.canvas.delete(self.queue.pop())
```

Comment: yup ill edit my answer

Comment: I see your edit, thanks, but you can check in the documentation that  [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) objects have no such `pop()` method.

Comment: wow yeah I just realised that. I just tried now to replace it with self.canvas.dequeue(self.queue) but still getting an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to write you own class. Python provides a `Queue` data structure in its standard library. You can use `deque` data structure from `collections`.

```
from collections import deque
q = deque()
q.append(5)
print q.pop()
```

Refer to the documentation for `deque` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

In your case, simply create a `deque` object instead of a `Queue` object.

```
from collections import deque
class Recta:
    def __init__(self, height=60, width=80 ):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.create_buttons()
        self.canvas = Canvas(root)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.queue = deque()  



def remove_triangle(self):
    if not self.queue.is_empty(): 
         self.canvas.delete(self.queue.pop())
```

Comment: so would i simply go q = deque() self.canvas.q(self.queue) ??

Comment: @M.Jones Which Python version are you using? If you are using Python3, you need to import deque from collections.

Comment: 3.4.1. this is the error I'm getting >>> ImportError: No module named 'Queue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110000/discussion-between-user161151-and-m-jones).

Comment: yeah thats what I have done. I just tried your code I'm getting an error >>>IndexError: pop from an empty deque

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at Python documentation for Queue right now ([see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)) and I fail to see a method called pop. Maybe that's the reason of your error. However, what I can see is the following method:

Queue.get([block[, timeout]])
Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is available. If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and raises the Empty exception if no item was available within that time. Otherwise (block is false), return an item if one is immediately available, else raise the Empty exception (timeout is ignored in that case).

New in version 2.3: The timeout parameter.

Maybe it serves your purpose.